# Unable to access internet on Vmware

Tags: networking, windows-7, internet, vmware

I have a Windows 7 host, and Ubuntu 16.04 as a guest operating system over VMware, I've been trying for a few days and have been unable to access the internet over the guest operating system.

My current configuration looks like this:

VM => Settings:
[image]

Network Editor:
[image]

`ifconfig` command from the Ubuntu desktop:
[image]

`ipconfig` command from the Windows 7 host desktop:
[image]

Interfaces file from `/etc/network`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

My question being, is there something simple that I'm missing here that will not allow me to connect to the internet?

Comment: you have no gateway, add your host as gateway on the guest VM, or change from NAT to bridged.

Comment: `add your host as gateway on the guest VM` What do you mean?

Comment: @warhansen, how did you infer this?

Comment: Your default gateway is empty on the iconfig. On you Linux host add: `gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` which is the Host's IP. Because your host is NAT'ed it will do the rest

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and add these lines:

```
# The primary network interface
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet dhcp
```

`ens33` is the logical name of the NIC and may be different for other operating systems.

Don't change anything of the loopback interface.

Save the file and run `sudo ifup ens33`.

Comment: This worked for me! OP should select it as correct answer.

Comment: this worked for me, too. You saved my days

Comment: Finally a solution that works!!

Comment: I had to add ens34 and that did the trick.  Thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
I have removed all the network cards and readded them - not sure if this was a requirement but after I did that I decided to reinstall the VM Player.
Then downloaded VMPlayer and ran the installer.
I chose Repair
then restarted the host machine.